# openBuilder from OpenContainer (animations Package) builds twice

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When I use

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SolvedQuizDetailsPage(),
  ),
);
```

`SolvedQuizDetailsPage` (it's a StatelessWidget) calls `@override build` only once (which is expected behavior). But when I use OpenContainer:

```
 return FutureBuilder(
  future: SolvedQuiz.index(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<SolvedQuiz>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => OpenContainer(
          openBuilder: (context, _) {
            return SolvedQuizDetailsPage();
          },
          closedBuilder: (context, open) => ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[i].quiz.title),
            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[i].quiz.description),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: DeliverableIcon(status: snapshot.data[i].status),
            ),
            // onTap: open,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  },
);
```

The widget is built twice

[This print () is in the first line of @override build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXauM.png)

And that's not all, When I come back
[using this button for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsFZ.png)

[Build it a third time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUTkL.png)

I need the widget to be built only once because every time it is built it must make an http request and in this case it makes multiple unwanted requests.

**EDIT:
When I remove all breakpoints this happens:**

[ui identical x lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZa9U.png)

Comment: Hi man, I'm facing same problem, did you found any solution for it

Comment: I noticed the same, the widget returned by the openBuilder is created twice when the button is clicked, and once more when it's closed

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `length` of your `data`. `ListView.builder` repeat build depending on its `itemCount` property. If you want to build your `SolvedQuizDetailsPage` only once, either remove it from the `ListView` or change the `itemCount` to 1

Comment: I had already thought about that but no, the problem is not that. The openBuilder is called only when clicking inside the object, so in theory it should not affect the number of elements in the list since it is one level up in the widget tree